# AMQP connection

Tags: rabbitmq, freebsd, amqp

Running RabbitMQ - rabbitmq-3.2.3_2
with pecl-amqp - 1.3.0
php55-5.5.9
on FreeBSD 9.2 amd64

all seems to work fine.

But while querying we got such error from amqp

> [AMQPConnectionException]
>    Library error: a socket error occurred - Potential login failure.

Tried almost everything  - downgrading AMQP to 1.0.9, deleting and adding user to RabbitMQ
but still nothing, changing permissions.
Anyone got same error? Or Any solutions?

Comment: http://pecl.php.net/package/amqp - 1.3.0 beta 2013-11-25 - i dont think its old, and in FreeBSD ports 1.0.9 is up to date, and 1.2.0 is stable...

Comment: [AMQPChannelException] Library error: a socket error occurred - the same

Comment: Yeah, 1.3 is fresh enough. And what about librabbitmq version?

Comment: rabbitmq-c-0.0.1_1  librabbitmq.so.3, also compiled rabbitmq-c-0.5.0 - not working(

Comment: Hmm, I had experience with FreeBSD and it works like a charm with amqp and rabbit. I even has no clue why it happens. You can try raw consumers from librabbitmq bundle. Maybe you have to experiment with Centos or Ubuntu? In addition, which php version do you use.

Comment: No, no, FreeBSD ftw) php i mentioned above php55-5.5.9

Comment: I run the same configuration on fresh centos 6.5 and ubuntu 13.10 and it works pretty well. Maybe there are some odd network configuration? Try to run C-based consumer (https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c/tree/master/tools) from librabbitmq package.

Answer (score 0):

I found this error today when creating a new user. The problem was that the password had special characters. I just changed the password by removing the special characters and could log in normally.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the library you use Raniel. I used to work with **robomq.io** and once had the same issue. If your library organizes your host, vhost, username, password into a AMQP URI like amqp://username:password@host:5672/vhost, then you will have this issue with special characters in any of these variables.
But some libraries are smart enough not to use this URI format, or will translate plain text into hexadecimal ASCII code, e.g. "/" into "%2f".